# Using QPainter with QImage in a loop not in a main thread

Tags: qt, qpainter, qimage

With  this simple loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<levels;i++)
{
    QImage stub(QSize(w,h),QImage::Format_RGB888);

    QPainter painter(&stub);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Monospace",8));
    painter.setPen(Qt::magenta);
    painter.drawText(stub.rect(),
                     Qt::AlignVCenter|Qt::AlignCenter,
                     QString("LAYER-%1").arg(i));

    stub.save(QString("layer%1.jpg").arg(i),"JPG");
}
```

I get a funny result:

[image: layer0]
[image: layer1]
[image: layer3]

Note the layer number printed on the image.
This looks like some buffering problem. I should also mention that this loop runs not in the main thread.
How to synchronize QPaitner and QImage saving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this nice bug.

You are using uninitialized `QImage`!

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-2

> **Warning:** This will create a **QImage** with **uninitialized data**. Call fill() to fill the image with an appropriate pixel value before
>   drawing onto it with **QPainter**.

So in each iteration same piece of memory is is assigned to `QImage`, which previously was owned by previous `QImage`. You were unlucky and in first iteration you have clear piece of memory instead some garbage values.

Call fill method to fix this.